# Adding own jQuery plugin to enother site and take data on server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, plugins

I have problem about architecture understanding about my idea.
I want to create my own plugin in jQuery and use plugin on another sites. 
I'll try to describe in detail  of the system and I hope that you will help me understand the right approach.
OK, I have service where user can registered and use his Admin Panel. When user registered, system generate his ID identification.
Then system generate Installation code  that the user can use to his site.
Example code installation: 
The main work of the plug-in will transfer the files from another site to Admin Panel in my server.

How I can create my plugin example, that will be able to connect to another site and transfer file from another site to AdminPanel User on my server (Server have MYSQL dataBase, my Admin Pane wrote on ASP.NET MVC)? 
And how I can transfer data information (file, another data) from plugin to my server.
Can you tell me the optimal way in Framework for this task.

Comment: "The optimal way" is to try something, if you don't try, you won't succeed. jQuery is a possibility, asp.net with the code behind... Currently this question is too opinion oriented

Comment: Of course you are right. But I don't fully understand the architecture of the plugin. If I have plugin files of scripts and styles, how the plugin will work if only one url will generate a service? Will I be able to handle all the files from the main one, which will only accept user ID?

Comment: If you can modify both end, create event on both side, than you control the chat. If you can only modify one side... well you can use the existing call on the other side but not more. For what is about using web services, it is easy to do in ASP.net, my personal opinion is include everything in an ASP.net project and use SFTP to transfer files from a place to another... i don't know for the rest